# Value of local variable unused error

Tags: variables, button, local, public, findviewbyid

I am making a button that will take you to another page. I've done one button and it worked perfectly. But when I try another I get an error that stops it working.

```
Button bWebs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Webs);
    bUtuube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent("com.tssandroid.tssphone.TUTORIALTWO"));
```

I am getting the error at `"bWebs"` the second word. The error is "The value of the local variable `bWebs` is not used". How do I fix this?

Comment: actually you get a warning, not an error. Notice that you set the `onClickListener` on `bUtuube` button, not on `bWebs`. Change the `bUtuube.setOnClickListener` to `bWebs.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Ah ok, cheers. I guess i didnt see that... :P